# Different project on the same base-directory (or share a single file between projects)

Tags: scala, sbt

My initial setup had two separate projects (sbt 1.2.6);

- a web app (huge codebase, lot of dependencies, slow compile)
- a command-line app (basically one file with 3-4 separate dependencies)

The feature request came in; we should show the "valid" values in the command line app. The valid values are in an enum in the web app. So I fired up the sbt documentation and came up with an idea which looked like this;

```scala
//main webapp
lazy val core = project
  .in(file("."))
  .withId("core") //I tried this just in case, not helped...
  //... here comes all the plugins and deps

//my hack to get a single-file compile
lazy val `feature-signer-helper` = project
  .in(file("."))
  .withId("feature-signer-helper")
  .settings(
    target := { baseDirectory.value / "target" / "features" },
    sources in Compile := {
      ((scalaSource in Compile).value ** "Features.scala").get
    }
  )

//the command line app
lazy val `feature-signer` = project
  .in(file("feature-signer"))
  .dependsOn(`feature-signer-helper`)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= signerDeps
  )
```

The problem is that it seems like, that whatever the last `lazy val xxx = project.in(file(y))` that will be the only project for the `y` dir.

Also, I don't want to move that one file to a separate directory structure... And logically the command line app and the web app are not "depends on" each other, they have different dependencies (and really different build times).

My questions are;

- is there any quick-win in this situation? (I will copy the file worst-case...)
- why we have this rich project and source settings if I can't bind them to the same dir?

EDIT:

The below code can copy the needed file (if you have the same dir structure). I'm not super happy with it, but it works. Still interested in other methods.

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object FeaturesCopyTask {
  val featuresCopyTask = {
    sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
      val outFile = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "Features.scala"
      val rootDirSrc = (Compile / baseDirectory).value / ".." / "src"
      val inFile: File = (rootDirSrc ** "Features.scala").get().head

      IO.copyFile(inFile, outFile, preserveLastModified = true)

      Seq(outFile)
    }.taskValue
  }
}
lazy val `feature-signer` = project
  .in(file("feature-signer"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= signerDeps,
    FeaturesCopyTask.featuresCopyTask
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have the tree be something more like

```
+- core/
+- webapp/
+- cli/
```

- `core` is the small amount (mostly model type things) that `webapp` and `cli` have in common
- `webapp` depends on `core` (among many other things)
- `cli` depends on `core` (and not much else)

So the `build.sbt` would be something like

```
lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  // yadda yadda yadda

lazy val webapp = (project in file("webapp"))
  .dependsOn(core)
  // yadda yadda yadda

lazy val cli = (project in file("cli"))
  .dependsOn(core)
  // yadda yadda yadda

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(
    core,
    webapp,
    cli
  )
```

Comment: If we would start this from zero, or if it would be clear at the beginning that we will have a CLI app I would started the project structure like that too...

Comment: It's not that hard to pull out the core from the webapp (unless the classes themselves are really poorly factored, in which case the refactoring to enable pulling out core is going to pay dividends anyway).

Comment: It is not about "how hard" but rather than how much work for what benefit. For one file share I would need to move all of our files. My other fix would be to open an api with the data of that file, and the CLI app would ask the valid options via HTTP. I think this is still a bit better :D